# Prestashop plugin for tracking unknown api calls changing order status

Tags: php, logging, prestashop

I find in many Prestashop platforms the following:

[image: my order history in PS v.1.7]

We have a traffic light system to block orders, but when the order is invoiced is going back to the previous status

I try to write this plugin below but it's not logging api calls to monitor which ip/system made this modification.
Order status are set as below:

2-Processing (paid)
3-Exported (invoice made)
4-Shipping preparation (logistics API pick up the order details)
5-Complete(order closed by logistics API when it sent the tracking code)

The portal is able to set the order to exported (laravel cron job).

Many delivered (complete) orders are now back to Exported status.

Is it the logistics is it the portal?

Is it the cache?

The override of the web service is not working and it is displaying in the order just an empty section.
I have sent request in postman:

a) first I got all the order fields
MYSITE/api/orders/258 (258 is the id of an order I modified
b) I copied the same body from the get and modify just the order status
and made the call `MYSITE/api/orders/258?ws_key=MYWEBSERVICEKEY`

```
//order_history_api//orderhistoryapi//orderhistoryapi.php:
```

```
<?php
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}

$autoloadPath = __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
if (file_exists($autoloadPath)) {
    require_once $autoloadPath;
}

use PrestaShop/PrestaShop/Core/Module/WidgetInterface;

class OrderHistoryAPI extends Module
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'orderhistoryapi';
        $this->tab = 'administration';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->author = 'Enrico Bisco';
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = ['min' => '1.7', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_];
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('Order History API');
        $this->description = $this->l('Displays API users in the order history section');
    }

    
    public function install()
    {
        $prefix = ""._DB_PREFIX_. "";
        $sql = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `'._DB_PREFIX_.'api_logs` (
              `id_api_log` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
              `api_key` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
              `request` TEXT NOT NULL,
              `caller_ip` TEXT NOT NULL,
              `date_add` DATETIME NOT NULL,
              `order_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
              `order_status` INT(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (`id_api_log`)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8' ;


        //$sql = str_replace('PREFIX_', _DB_PREFIX_, $sql);
        $result = Db::getInstance()->execute($sql);

        return parent::install() &&
            $this->registerHook('displayAdminOrder') &&
            $result;
    }


    public function uninstall()
    {
        // Elimina la tabella 'api_logs'
        $sql = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'api_logs`;';
        $result = Db::getInstance()->execute($sql);

        // Esegui la disinstallazione del modulo genitore e verifica l'esito della cancellazione della tabella
        return parent::uninstall() && $result;
    }


    
    public function getApiUserInfo($order_id)
    {
        $db = Db::getInstance();
        $query = new DbQuery();
        $query->select('al.api_key, al.request, al.caller_ip, al.date_add, al.order_status, wa.key, wa.description, wp.resource, wp.method, al.order_id')
            ->from('api_logs', 'al')
            ->leftJoin('webservice_account', 'wa', 'wa.key = al.api_key')
            ->leftJoin('webservice_permission', 'wp', 'wp.id_webservice_account = wa.id_webservice_account')
            ->where('al.order_id = ' . (int)$order_id);
        return $db->executeS($query);
    }

    public function hookDisplayAdminOrder($params)
    {
        $order_id = $params['id_order'];
        $api_info = $this->getApiUserInfo($order_id);
        $this->context->smarty->assign('api_info', $api_info);
        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/hook/order_history_api.tpl');
    }
    


}
```

//order_history_api//orderhistoryapi//config.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


    orderhistoryapi
    <![CDATA[Order History API]]>
    <![CDATA[your_module_version]]>
    <![CDATA[Displays API users in the order history section.]]>
    <![CDATA[Your Name]]>
    <![CDATA[administration]]>
    0
    0
```

orderhistoryapi//views//templates//hook//order_history_api.tpl:

```php
        <h3>
          {l s='Chiamate API esegite' mod='orderfiles'}
        </h3>
      
    
  
  
    
      <h3>{l s='Chiamate API per modificare Stato dell/'ordine' d='Shop.Theme.Customeraccount'}</h3>
      
        
          
            {l s='Date' d='Shop.Theme.Global'}
            {l s='Status' d='Shop.Theme.Global'}
            {l s='Info' d='Shop.Theme.Global'}
          
        
        
            {foreach from=$order.history item=state}
                
                    {$state.history_date}
                    
                        
                            {$state.ostate_name}
                        
                    
                    {assign var='api_order_info' value=$api_info|@array_filter|@reset}
                    {if $api_order_info && $api_order_info.date_add|date_format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' == $state.history_date|date_format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'}
                        
                            API Key usata: {$api_order_info.api_key}<br>
                            IP: {$api_order_info.caller_ip}<br>
                            Risorsa: {$api_order_info.resource}<br>
                            Metodo: {$api_order_info.method}<br>
                            Key usata: {$api_order_info.key}<br>
                            Nome webservice: {$api_order_info.description}<br>
                        
                    {else}
                         Nessuna API call 
                    {/if}
                
            {/foreach}
        
      
      
        {foreach from=$order.history item=state}
          
            {$state.history_date}
            
              
                {$state.ostate_name}
              
            
          
        {/foreach}
```

orderhistoryapi//override//classes//WebserviceRequest.php:

```
<?php

class WebserviceRequest extends WebserviceRequestCore
{
    public function executeRequest()
    {
        $response = parent::executeRequest();

        $db = Db::getInstance();
        $caller_ip = isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : 'Unknown';

        $is_order_update_api_call = $this->checkIfOrderUpdateApiCall($this->url, $this->method);
        $order_id = null;
        $order_status = null;

        if ($is_order_update_api_call) {
            $url_parts = explode('/', $this->url);
            $order_id = (int)$url_parts[array_search('orders', $url_parts) + 1];

            $order = new Order((int)$order_id);
            $order_status = $order->current_state;
        }

        $db->insert('api_logs', [
            'api_key' => pSQL($this->_key),
            'request' => pSQL($this->url),
            'caller_ip' => pSQL($caller_ip),
            'date_add' => pSQL(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')),
            'order_id' => pSQL($order_id),
            'order_status' => pSQL($order_status)
        ]);

        return $response;
    }

    private function checkIfOrderUpdateApiCall($url, $method)
    {
        if ($method === 'PUT' || $method === 'POST') {
            if (strpos($url, '/orders/') !== false) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```